# How do I extend the storage space in my NAS server?

Tags: raid, centos, storage, freenas, hardware-raid

I have a NAS server (Dell R310 and FreeNAS OS) with RAID 1 and 2 x 250GB, and 2 slots for hot plug disk space are free. It is using hardware RAID.

But the disk space is almost full, how can I extend the space without troubles? Or is there any USB solution? How do you solve this disk and space issue?

Note: CentOS is used in another Dell server to push the uploads and backups to the NAS server.

Comment: Are you unable to take the NAS offline for a short time for this upgrade?

Comment: @sblair: yes from my CentOS, i disabled the backup/dumping to NAS. I can put NAS for 1 day out of service and do the repairing yes.

Comment: If you have two spare hard drive ports, can you simply add two larger drives (presumably also in RAID 1), copy the data, then ditch the old drives? (But because you are already using FreeNAS, I'd really recommend you consider ZFS, rather than hardware RAID.)

Comment: Its a nice idea. I will do that for another setup. With this current setup can i have something like USB extension without changing the whole core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herea are the possible options:

- Replace drives one by one with higher capacity drives and then extend volume and re-size file system.
- You can also add more drives and either create another volume on them or extend the existing volume followed by re-sizing of the file system.
- You can also add two drives of higher capacity to free slots, create a larger volume on them and then copy your old volume over and use old drives elsewhere.

As far as I remember FreeNAS should be able to do all this.